# Power Bi extract strings from column based on a code list

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column of drawing numbers and a list of codes. I want to see if any of the drawing numbers contain any codes, I just can't seem to find a way to compare the list and extract these codes.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.

Comment: This ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000061/text-contains-for-multiple-values-power-query/73000409#73000409 If not post input and desired output samples

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea how to get a table with columns drawing no. - list of codes. Hope, this will help, if not add a data sample and a result sample.

```
VAR drawings=VALUES(myTbl[drawing])

VAR drawingsAndCodes=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            drawings
            ,"codes",VAR dr=[drawing] 
                     VAR codes=VALUES(myTbl[code])
                        RETURN CONCATENATEX(
                            FILTER(
                                codes
                                ,Search([code],dr,1,0)>0),[code],";"))
  
  
RETURN
    drawingsAndCodes
```

The Measure for matrix

```
VAR dr=SELECTEDVALUE(myTbl[drawing]) 
VAR codes=VALUES(myTbl[code])
RETURN CONCATENATEX(
                        FILTER(
                            codes
                            ,Search([code],dr,1,0)>0),[code],";"))
```

Comment: i get an error `The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value`.

Comment: It returns a table, not a single value. Add a result sample, this will help to get a right output.

Comment: Do you want to put the measure into a matrix?

Comment: Do you have any linkage for columns?

Comment: I added the measure for matrix

Comment: Thanks the measure at the bottom works, Follow up Is there a way to make it so that the measure matches with the code but then brings back the value in a different column in the same table the code is in?

Comment: Great! Are you talking about adding of a calculated column?

Comment: Not a 100% sure it will works. You can change `SELECTEDVALUE(myTbl[drawing])` to `CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(myTbl[drawing]))` this will put the exptession into a row context.

Comment: @adamWadsworth did we solve the issue?