# Match words in string but preserve the order using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is based on a previous question:

[Text.Contains for multiple values power query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000061/text-contains-for-multiple-values-power-query)

Basically want to achieve the same thing but ensure that the order of the match prioritises the word found first in the string. i.e. Children, Adult and not Adult, Children on the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this works for you

fuzzy match:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Text.Split([Data]," ")),
#"Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(#"Expanded Custom1", {"Custom"}, ListToMatch, {"Column1"}, "ListToMatch", JoinKind.LeftOuter, [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true]),
#"Expanded ListToMatch" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ListToMatch", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded ListToMatch", {"Data", "Index"}, {{"Match", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Distinct([Column1]), Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

or text.contains:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Split([Data]," ")),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn( #"Expanded Custom", "Found",  (x) => Table.SelectRows(ListToMatch, each Text.Contains(x[Custom],[Column1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
#"Expanded Found" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Found", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Found", each ([Column1] <> null)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Data", "Index"}, {{"data.1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Distinct([Column1]), Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})                                     
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

to generate

[image]

**ALTERNATE**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Split([Data]," ")),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom"),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn( #"Expanded Custom", "Found",  (x) => Table.SelectRows(ListToMatch, each Text.Contains(x[Custom],[Column1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
#"Expanded Found" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Found", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Found", each ([Column1] <> null)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Data", "Index"}, {{"Match", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Column1], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})                                     
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

for

[image]